# Why does emacs not work in iTerm anymore?

Tags: command-line, emacs, iterm

```
$ emacs -batch -l dunnet*
zsh: command not found: emacs
$
```

I tried to run this in iTerm, but the error came up.
Please help me with this, this could also help a lot of people. (I wanna play my game!)

*this is a game in iTerm, for anyone who's interested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

emacs used to be bundled with macOS, but apparently this is no longer the case since Catalina (10.15):

> Emacs no longer being bundled with macOS Catalina confirms once and for all that Vim is the superior editor
>
> by @SmileyKeith ([source](https://mobile.twitter.com/SmileyKeith/status/1143252734696517632))

(Couldn't find a better source; please edit if you can)

You can download Emacs for macOS from https://emacsformacosx.com/.  Assuming you install it into `/Applications`, you can start it with:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -batch -l dunnet
```

Unlike the bundled version of Emacs, this one comes with window system support.  If you want to play Dunnet in an Emacs window, try:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -f dunnet
```

Comment: thanks this helped a lot